# Indicating unaligned access to Clang for ARM compatibility

Tags: c, gcc, arm, clang

I'm parsing a file format by mapping a file to memory and accessing it through C struct definitions. The file format uses packed structures, so I cannot guarantee that a field will align to a word boundary.

The parsing works just fine, unfortunately in certain cases the optimizer may wreak havoc. In particular, compiling for armv7 there are certain load instructions that require word alignment and others that do not. Consider this snippet:

```
#define PACKED __attribute__((packed))

typedef struct PACKED _Box_mvhd {
    union {
        struct {
            int32_t creation_time;
            int32_t modification_time;
            int32_t time_scale;
            int32_t duration;
            ...
        } v0;
    } data;
} Box_mvhd;

Container mvhd = find_single_box(&moov, 'mvhd');
if (mvhd.boxStart) {
    Box_mvhd *mvhdBox = mvhd.mvhd;
    if (0 == mvhdBox.box.version) {
        uint32_t ts = ntohl(mvhdBox->data.v0.time_scale);
        uint32_t dur = ntohl(mvhdBox->data.v0.duration);
        ...
    }
}
```

In `-O0` (debugging) the innermost block is emitted as the following assembly, which works properly:

```
ldr r1, [r0, #24]
ldr r2, [r0, #20]
```

In `-O2` however the compiler realizes these fields are adjacent and generates this assembly:

```
ldrdeq  r2, r3, [r0, #20]
```

Unfortunately `LDRD` always generates an alignment fault (by spec and in practice). So I need a way to inform the compiler of this issue effectively. Ideally this could be done with an attribute on the struct. It's also possible that this is a bug with the compiler or ARM backend, but I'll give them the benefit of the doubt.

I'm compiling with Xcode 4.2 (clang 3.0) targeting armv7 for iPhone.

Comment: Get rid of your packed structures and write a proper parser. Actually I'm confused how your code is faulting, since the structure is properly aligned and should not need padding. Is the pointer `mvhdBox` (`r0`) itself misaligned? If so, you should just `memcpy` the data into a properly aligned buffer, access it from there, and remove the packing attribute.

Comment: What does clang give for `alignof(Box_mvhd)`?  (if clang doesn't support `alignof()` natively, you can use something like `#define alignof(t) offsetof(struct { char c; t x; }, x)`)

Comment: @R..: his code is faulting because he's casting an unaligned pointer to `Box_mvhd *`, then accessing the fields.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, but mvhdBox itself is misaligned because it can occur at an arbitrary offset in the file.

Comment: Then don't access it in-place. First `memcpy` it from the original `unsigned char[]` file buffer to a genuine (and thus properly aligned) object of type `Box_mvhd`.

Answer (score 4):

The issue isn't that the fields of the struct don't have the required alignment, it's that you're casting an arbitrary pointer to a pointer to your struct, and the pointer you're casting doesn't have the required alignment of the struct.  Strictly speaking this is undefined behavior.

Instead, `memcpy` your data from the source buffer to your struct.  `memcpy` is fast, and guaranteed to handle whatever alignment you throw at it.

Comment: Thanks, this does work and is the fix we have in place. It would be nice if the copying could be avoided in general, because some of the boxes in the file can be very large (though not in this case).

Comment: If the box is variable-size, you may not need to copy the whole thing, just the fixed-size header. If the remaining data is byte data, you'll have no trouble accessing it in-place. If it's larger types, you might make some macros for reading it, or just stick with the copy you're doing if it's not too bad.

Comment: @mjr: If you need to do some processing on large arbitrarily-aligned buffers, consider using NEON via intrinsics -- NEON load/store can handle arbitrary alignment.

Comment: @mjr Then it depends on how you get the data, if you read from a file/pipe/socket or similar - you might be able align the buffer you read data into so it is already properly aligned for your struct.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, unaligned pointers to packed structs are completely fine. But you need to make sure, that the `-mcpu` and `-march` parameters are set correctly during compile. Some ARM CPUs support unaligned `ldrd`, others don't.

Yes, unaligned access is non-standard and a compiler extension, but it's perfectly safe unless you pass a pointer to a member of a packed struct to another function by accident.

Here, the problems seems to be that the struct inside the union is not declared as packed. You can verify the alignment of the struct members using the `alignof` operator. It's similar to the `sizeof` operator. If the `alignof` operator tells you, that the alignment of the struct and its members is `1` and gcc still emits code using `ldrd`, then you're either facing a compiler bug or the command line options are wrong.

Also note, that the code for `-O0` might have been wrong to begin with! (unless your target arm architecture supports unaligned `ldr`). Using the packed attribute resets the alignment of struct members to 1, meaning that clang should have emitted eight `ldrb` instructions instead of two `ldr`.

And yes, as others already told you, the only safe and portable way of accessing unaligned data from plain C without any compiler extensions and without the risk of making hard to find mistakes (like passing an unaligned pointer on to a function) is by using `memcpy`.

Comment: Update: with `-march=armv7`, clang 3.3 generated lots of ldrb instructions when accesing `data.v0.duration`. GCC is more clever, and uses `ldr`, since armv7 supports unalign `ldr`. I did not have to change the declarion of the struct at all! You may try to add the packed attribute to all struct members. I believe, you're clearly experiencing a llvm bug, unless you options are wrong.